# Make DefaultMessageListenerContainer with subscriptionShared and subscriptionDurable

Tags: spring, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I want to use `subscriptionShared` and `subscriptionDurable` in `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` due to having a shared durable subscription between all consumers.

After Tomcat start I see this log message many times and it seems my topic has a problem:

```
Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination x.y.z trying to recover. cause:org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createSharedDurableConsumer (Ljavax/jms/Topic;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/jms/MessageConsumer"
```

My Spring version is `4.3.8`. I use ActiveMQ Artemis `2.9.0` and JMS `2.0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the fact that the error message contains `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession` it appears to me that you're using the OpenWire JMS client from ActiveMQ 5.x. This JMS client doesn't support JMS 2.0 and therefore doesn't support shared durable subscriptions. You need to use the JMS client from ActiveMQ Artemis.