# Artemis durable subscriptions for multicast address with JMS

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

With JMS I want to create some durable subscriptions for a topic (multicast address). In case of one duarble subscriptions it works, but in case of more, it does not and errors occur.

These are my listeners: maybe the properties are not correctly filled?

```
 @JmsListener(destination = "VirtualTopic.test", id = "c1", subscription = "Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.test", containerFactory = "queueConnectionFactory")
public void receive1(String m) {

}


@JmsListener(destination = "VirtualTopic.test", id = "c2", subscription = "Consumer.B.VirtualTopic.test", containerFactory = "queueConnectionFactory")    
public void receive2(String m) {

}
```

This is the listenerFactory: I'm not sure about the last property.

```
    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory queueConnectionFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setClientId("brokerClientId");
        factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        factory.setSubscriptionShared(true);       **<-- needed for my case?**
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
        return connectionFactory;
    }
```

These are the error logs, when I set "factory.setSubscriptionShared(true);":

```
2020-04-17 11:23:44.485  WARN 7900 --- [enerContainer-3] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'VirtualTopic.test' - trying to recover. Cause: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createSharedDurableConsumer(Ljavax/jms/Topic;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/jms/MessageConsumer; 
2020-04-17 11:23:44.514 ERROR 7900 --- [enerContainer-3] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'VirtualTopic.test' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Broker: d1 - Client: brokerClientId already connected from /127.0.0.1:59979
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by the JMS specification, only one client with the same ID can connect. You're apparently using the same client ID for all your connections, i.e.:

```java
factory.setClientId("brokerClientId");
```

Try *not* setting the client ID and see how that goes.

Also, ensure you're using a JMS client implementation that actually supports JMS 2.0 (e.g. the ActiveMQ Artemis core JMS client).

Comment: Thx for your reply. Unfortunately you need that clientId for durbale subscriptions. Else you get error with : Cause: You cannot create a durable subscriber without specifying a unique clientID on a Connection

Comment: As noted in section 6.1.2 of the JMS 2 specification the client ID is mandatory for *unshared* durable subscriptions, but it is **optional** for shared durable subscriptions. It sounds like perhaps Spring JMS is using the wrong JMS API call to create the shared durable subscription.

Comment: I found another answer from you, which answers my problem ;) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57248768/make-defaultmessagelistenercontainer-with-subscriptionshared-and-subscriptiondur). I was using the ActiveMq 5.x JMS client, which does not support shared-durable subs. The reason for taking this was, that I wanted to use the wildcards for resolving virtualTopics naming convention. But this is not supported in **org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory** or **javax.jms.ConnectionFactory**. Whats the difference between those connection factories?

Comment: How can I send something to a dedicated queue of a topic, or to a subscription? With management console it is possible, and also receiving. But sending per jms does not somehow.

Comment: Virtual Topics are really specific to ActiveMQ 5.x. They aren't part of the JMS specification. It's not really wise to tie your applications to a broker-specific behavior which is why things like standards and APIs exist in the first place. I recommend you create an entirely new question for this as it's pretty different from shared durable subscriptions in JMS 2.